# phonegap plugin for select a video from the library

Tags: iphone, ipad

I need to be able to select  a video from the library and upload it to my server.

I can record a new video (captureVideo) and upload it (filetransfer)no problem, but I can´t seem to find any way to open the videolibrary and select a video and then upload it.

Is there any way to do this? Change MediaType somehow on
navigator.camera.getPicture?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem as follows:

```
function ideaCommitLibraryVideoAttach() {
if(PhoneGap.available) {
    var options = {quality: 80};
    options["sourceType"] = 0;
    options["correctOrientation"] = true;
    options["allowEdit"] = true;
    options["mediaType"] = 1;
    navigator.camera.getPicture(ideaCommitLibraryVideoReceive, ideaCommitVideoAttachFail, options);
}
}

function ideaCommitLibraryVideoReceive(data) {
if(PhoneGap.available) {
    var gotFS = function(fileSystem) {
        var fail = function() {notify("Can't open file!");};
        var gotFileEntry = function(fileEntry) {
            var fail = function() {notify("Can't write attachment in a temporary file!");};
            var gotFileWriter = function(fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                    ideaCommitVideoReceive([fileEntry]);
                };
                fileWriter.write(data);
            };
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
            file = fileEntry;
        };
        fileSystem.root.getFile("y"+ new Date().getTime()+".mp4", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);

    };
    var fail = function() {notify("Can't open file system!");};
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}
}
```

The only remaining problem with this is as follows: We did not find a method to access the video as file, but only as base64 encoded. Thus we are not able to give the user a preview possibility after selecting the video from inside of the App. Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Hey Chagemei can you explain your code? I think I know what's going on, but it's not working for me so I need to figure out why ;) What does the function ideaCommitVideoReceive([fileEntry) do?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to preview an element from library or a recent capture is to use a native

html5 video, image or audio tag with the uri returned in the success call of the getPicture,

capturePicture, captureVideo or captureAudio... hope it helps.