# Select video in library

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to select a video from the library with PhoneGap.
If so, with what version of PhoneGap.

I've tried to do it the same way I do with pictures, but videos are not shown in the library.

(Don't point out to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383518/phonegap-plugin-for-select-a-video-from-the-library) : It is not what I want)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do u need something like this?

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(successFn, errorFn, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: this.photoDestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA  });
```

It's slightly different in Cordova 5.4.1:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO
  });
```

Related docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera#module_Camera.DestinationType

Comment: If you specify the MediaType to be VIDEO you will only get the videos.